# Jenkins how to skip Maven-antrun-plugin to executing build.xml files in maven build with command

Tags: maven, jenkins, ant

I want to skip compiling ant `build.xml` files in my Jenkins workspace like skipping Java test with the command parameter:

```
-Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

This command is not skipping ant build scripts:

```
-Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install
```

Can someone help me in this regards?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Why should Maven call the `build.xml`? Do you use Maven-antrun-plugin? A standard pom.xml is not calling any ant builds.

Comment: @ JF Meier yes im using Maven-antrun-plugin.which is executing ant build.xml scripts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To skip maven-antrun-plugin in your pom.xml, use `-Dmaven.antrun.skip=true`.